# Fill Brush makes streaky lines to image origin

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

[image: The fill brush problem]

Using a fill brush on my character gives me the above result.  There are no UV points at the origin, and painting the character with a non-fill brush does not give me these results.  Every piece of the character I try to fill leaves me with these streaky lines converging at the image origin.  What could be causing this?